# Where could found DatePicker "doctolib looklike" calendar?

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, calendar

I need to integrate a calendar component like this provided in doctolib site.

The aim is to allow users to pick a date from available RDVs dates as in the attached [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWO87.png).

I have found open source code on Github : https://github.com/doctolib/calendar-1. But i didn't yet found which is the right component for my need.

Thank you for your help in advance. I am gratefull too if you have other open source solution.

Regards,